# Change The default settings of projects in NetBeans

Tags: java, c++, netbeans

I have netBeans 7.4 with openJDK 7 running on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 System.
I want to change the default "Source/Binary format" in java project setting to JDK 6 (I DO NOT WANT TO INSTALL OpenJDK 6 because I have openJDK 7 which is compatable).
Also in C++ Project, I want to change the default "Console Type" in the "Run" section of project settings  from "Internal" which causes some problems to "Standard Output".

Comment: If I quite understand your question you want to change Source / Binary format in java project setting. To do this click the right button of your mouse on the project and select properties and then select the Source tab JDK 6 in combobox.

Comment: A minor addition to what @rpirez mentioned - in both cases you should hit the button with the arrow (pointing down) - a pull-down menu will be opened, then you'll be able to change the setting

Comment: I said I want to change the default setting, meaning all new project must use that same new setting, not the setting of one single project I know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Probably you need to highlight the *default* in your question. As for what you want - I think it's buried in NetBeans configuration files, it won't be easy to find it

Answer (score 0):

From the NetBeans doc:
Note: If a compatible JDK installation cannot be found, you might need to manually add a path to the JDK installation directory by doing the following:
Open the netbeans.conf file located in the netbeans/etc directory in a text editor.
Enter the location of a compatible JDK installation for the netbeans_jdkhome option. The default location in Windows is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67 or similar.
Save the netbeans.conf file and run the executable file in the netbeans/bin directory.

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html

Find the spot that needs changing by ctl-F JDK and tab down until you see where it is specifying the path. Hopefully your new JDK is located in the same folder and you only have to change the version number.

You should save a copy of the conf file as confold or something in case something goes wrong.